# Toolbar in fragment appearing below action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to follow the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment) on how to properly create a toolbar in a fragment. However, when I follow the example in the doc, by toolbar appears below the action bar rather than inside of it.

[image]

(Note that the "Done" button is not in the action bar).

Most examples I've found through searching stackoverflow seem to use `setSupportActionBar`, but I don't want to use this because the docs are clear that this shouldn't be used with a toolbar that only appears in one fragment.

Here is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<CityListFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

city_list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

CityListFragment.kt

```
class CityListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_list_fragment, container, false)

        val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.done_btn -> {
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/done_btn"
          android:title="Done"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this how android wants fragment-owned toolbars to look?

Answer (score 1):

There are some way to if you want to make custom toolbar in fragment respectively. Because you are showing your fragment over a activity so default toolbar will appear. You have to remove default toolbar from your activity. First way, go to theme and change style

```
         <style name="copy from your app" 
    parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

another way - add this line in activity class oncreate method

```
    supportActionBar?.hide()
```

another way -add this line in activity class oncreate method

```
  getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

all ways should be in activity.

Comment: I think if I did that it would also hide the action bar in the fragments where I don't have a toolbar. I think I'm just going to go with managing the activity's action bar through the fragment. I don't know why Google doesn't want us doing that, it seems so much easier.